# Route traffic from client to server on router's WAN port

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing

I have a TP-link tl-wr841nd home router, and I wish to make a small network for sharing and downloading files via a web browser interface. My basic setup is as shown below:

[image]

Currently, I have a customized web/file server connected to the router's WAN interface via a switch. Then I plan to have clients connect to the router's wifi connection and browse through the files available on the web server via the router. My question is, how do I redirect traffic from the clients to the web server via the router? Also, is the above plan workable? What other strategies are available to achieve the above? Keep in mind I really want to have the servers on a different network than the clients' network.

Comment: Hmm. Where is your internet connection?

Comment: There's no Internet connection. It's a closed network. Fully local

Comment: You could run a name service on your server and let the clients connect "the internet way"--by browsing to its web site.

Comment: @gbarry could u explain more

Answer (score 0):

If your client's default gateway is the wifi router, and the server's default gateway is the router's WAN address, your clients can reach the servers via IP address.  If you want to browse by name, you need a name server (also called a DNS server).

Comment: Let me see if I have understood this. I give both the router n server static IP addresses in the same network, point the server's gateway to the router's WAN address, then I can access the server via IP addressing? Also, can the DNS server run simultaneously on the web server?

Comment: Right.  Naturally, the router's WAN address and LAN address are on different subnets.  You can usually run a nameserver and a web server at the same time, depending on the server capacity.

Comment: That means I will point the DNS server address on the router to my server, right?

Comment: Wait, what about the router's default gateway? It seems the router must have one

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to be working. The router is asking for a default gateway when setting a static IP, which I don't know how to set up yet but it has to be there, and the wan interface cannot communicate with the LAN interface, tried pinging the LAN interface but nothing happens, so it seems they r not communicating.

Comment: Sine you're on a closed network, try setting the gateway to 0.0.0.0.  If that doesn't work, pick an unused address in the subnet.  Be sure to turn off NAT on the router (it's probably on by default).  Can you ping from LAN to WAN?

Comment: No I can't ping from LAN to WAN

Comment: what is the address and mask  you gave to the wan interface?

Comment: SERVER IP:192.168.0.2, server gateway: 192.168.0.1, mask: 255.255.255.0, Router WAN Addr: 192.168.0.1, router gateway:192.168.0.5, mask: 255.255.255.0, LAN Address: 192.168.5.1, mask: 255.255.255.0